# php match number for first 2 digits and length

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, digits, string-length

I would need to check in php if the number has 10 digit length and the first 2 digits need to be 09 and check for no space too please?

sample true number = 0912345678

Thanks
Ramin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using regular expressions, like this:

```
function checkNumber($number) {
    return !!preg_match('/^09\d{8}$/', "$number");
}
```

Or with simple string matching:

```
function checkNumber($number) {
    $number = trim("$number");
    if (strlen($number) != 10)
        return false;

    if (substr($number, 0, 2) != "09")
        return false;

    return trim($number, "0..9") == "";
}
```

Both methods gives same output:

```
var_dump([$number = '0912345678', checkNumber($number)]);
var_dump([$number = '9012345678', checkNumber($number)]);
var_dump([$number = '091234567', checkNumber($number)]);
var_dump([$number = '09123456788', checkNumber($number)]);

// array(2) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(10) "0912345678"
//   [1]=>
//   bool(true)
// }
// array(2) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(10) "9012345678"
//   [1]=>
//   bool(false)
// }
// array(2) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(9) "091234567"
//   [1]=>
//   bool(false)
// }
// array(2) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(11) "09123456788"
//   [1]=>
//   bool(false)
// }
```

Also, regexp approach is more simpler and flexible, imho.

Comment: Please add some information about how your code solves the Problem.

Comment: thanks so much. very helpful. I also tried below code and it worked too.  preg_match("/^([09]{2})([0-9]{9})$/", $cellNum)

Comment: @RaminRabii, but yours code gives `true` for numbers of 11 digits, also they can start with `09` **and** `90`, as `[09]{2}` means "two digits of `0` and `9`, in any order"

Comment: thanks so much for your advise. should change it to preg_match("/^([0]{1})([9]{1})([0-9]{8})$/", $cellNum);

Comment: =) there are no meaning in `[0]{1}` or `[9]{1}` constructions, as they can be replaced with simple `0` and `9`. so, you can use one of this patterns: `/^(09)(\d{8})$/`, `/^(09)([0-9]{8})$/`